# Possible to serialize node.js vm.script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serialization, fork

I'm experimenting with ways to pre-compile a large number of JS functions using node.js vm.script, so that I can call the functions multiple times without the overhead of recompiling each time. Note that I can't just include the functions in a module, because they are architecturally completely separate from the "core" code. That works fine--each compiled script is stored in an object and can be run as-needed.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to use this same model with multiple fork'ed child processes, so any child process can be used to run the compiled script. The question is how to serialize it, so I can pass it to the child. And more importantly, is there anything inherent in the script variable that would "tie" it to the process it was created in?

Comment: Hi @eric did you find my answer useful or did you find some other methods to serialize a js Script?

Comment: Hi @Cristiano - No, it was a concept we were working on, but since there didn't seem to be a relatively straightforward path to do it, we put it on the shelf. Frankly, JIT compiling of even fairly large JS scripts is trivial, so it hasn't been a high priority. But if a way to do this ever emerges, it's something I'd be interested in taking another look at.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid is not possible. The first hint is that the Script object doesn't have any method to retrieve the compiled code. Looking further inside the source code of node [here](https://github.com/nodejs/ecmascript-modules/blob/modules-lkgr/lib/vm.js) and [here](https://github.com/nodejs/ecmascript-modules/blob/39eb894099f633dc1f3bc82888d4b92e603be679/src/node_contextify.cc), it seems that the compiled object is stored inside a native C object. Therefore there's no means to serialize it from JS.